# Transfer a live call in twilio to another secondary number that is not in twilio - Python

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I am using the python SDK for handling twilio incoming calls. I have created a flask application for this. All calls coming in to my twilio number get routed through the flask application URL(Webhook). Now, when the call is in progress, I want to transfer the caller to a secondary number (which is not in twilio) and then disconnect my call with the caller once the connection is established between the caller and the secondary number.

Can someone tell me how this can be done in python?

I already tried calling a number but was not able to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: Have you tried starting a call conference with the secondary number once the initial call has been established?

Comment: I have tried it. But the conference feature requires the call transferer to stay on call. The call gets disconnected when the transferer disconnects.

Comment: Did you take a look at this blog post on [warm transfers with Python and Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/warm-phone-call-transfers-with-python-flask-and-twilio-voice.html)? It shows you how you can use a conference to make a transfer like this? Otherwise, what have you tried so far and what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the functionality you're trying to achieve, but, try this:

First grab the call id when Twilio hits your webhook and connects the incoming call
(in this example `CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38`)

Then when you're ready to transfer to the secondary number, make a POST request to instruct to switch to executing a new TwiML, like this:

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls("CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38") \
             .update(
                  method="POST",
                  url="http://example.com/transfer.xml"
              )

print(call.to)
```

---

The transfer.xml contains the `<Dial>` to the secondary number:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number>415-123-4567</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: With a call in progress, how do you initiate the POST?

Comment: @That1Guy https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress

Comment: Not what I asked, but ok.

Comment: @That1Guy I apologize if I did not understand your question. Executing the python code above will make a POST request.

Comment: Sorry - bad mood. I understand how to modify the call itself once a request has been made to my server. My question is how do I get there to begin with? ie: My users have a phone in their hand and want to transfer the caller to someone else. What is Step 1? How does a user create the POST request to my server? Or how do I return a response that allows the user to create another request? (If that makes sense)

Comment: @That1Guy no problem, I understand. I believe you could interact with the user by responding initially with TWIML which contains a "Gather" https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action which has an  "action" URL which executes the code above. You'll probably have to pass the call SID in the URL (If you have trouble, you could ask a new question with your specific details and we'll try to put together a demo and an answer.)